# How to make multicheck for post/page meta box

Tags: metabox

Please help me understand how to make Multicheck type for metabox. Search for all internet and nothing. Thanks.

---

### UPDATE

@Jan I have a headache from this function. I dont know whats wrong.I'm trying your method but nothing, then I'm trying get_posts but with this method I have too many troubles. With your method I get this error before content:

```
Warning: urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in Z:\home\mysite.net\www\wp-includes\query.php on line 1878
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $catids = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_mtb_multicheck',false);
        $limit = 10;
        query_posts( array('posts_per_page' => $limit, 'cat' => $catids, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );
    ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Content-->

<?php endwhile; ?>  
            <?php pagination(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
            <!--Error message here-->

<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to know what my vatiables return. Make this:

```
query_posts( array('posts_per_page' => $limit, 'cat' => print_r($catids), 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );
```

and get this on my page:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 )
```

I think it's my query_posts printed, not $catids. It's a big, big trouble. I feel myself like a nerd. Please help me.

Comment: @Denis: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean a series of checkboxes by "multicheck"? And are you talking about adding a new metabox, like on the post edit screen?

Comment: Yes Jan, I want to add a series of checkboxes like on the post edit screen. I make metabox by this tutorial http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html , but they doesn't include type multicheck.

Comment: @Denis: That code seems to include the checkbox type, how is this different from a "multicheck"? Can you update your question with an mock-up (sketch) image? If you use `@` before my name in a comment, like `@Jan`, I will get a notification and can reply sooner.

Comment: @Jan: Multicheck mean that you can check multiple item in one field, it's like category taxonomy where we can check several categories that include this post. We dont need to create checkbox for every category or another item we use array with items and multicheck help us check several items.

Comment: @Jan: I make somthing like this but it's check only one checkbox not several:
http://pastebin.com/TAKDe13u

Comment: @Denis: You don't have to use the "framework" described on that page to create meta boxes. What is the list of items that you want to display? If it's from WordPress, maybe you can already use an existing function.

Comment: @Denis: Your code is a good start, but maybe you have problems saving the values to the database and showing them correctly afterwards?

Comment: @Jan: At this time I just test this function, for example I use list of categories, but this only for example. Later I make somes different functions and this is not a Wordpress exist function. I'm not a coder and why I'm here. All I have I demonstrate you above. I think problem not in database it's from wrong code.

Comment: @Jan: On some forum I found this function for multicheck but this works with custom write panels maded by wefunction. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-a-checkbox-to-custom-write-panels?replies=8#post-1662649

Comment: @Jan: What you think? Is there any way to make multicheck working?

Comment: @Jan: I'm edit post. Can you explain why I have this error and how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post metadata can store multiple values either as distinct entries in the `postmeta` table, or as one entry with the value as a serialized PHP array. The serialization may require less code, but the distinct entries allow faster querying later ("give me all posts that have at least option A of the multicheck checked").

I took [the code you linked to](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html) and made the following changes to allow a "multicheck":

```
// in show():
// Line 254: replace it by:
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], 'multicheck' != $field['type'] /* If multicheck this can be multiple values */);
// Add the following to the switch:
case 'multicheck':
    foreach ( $field['options'] as $value => $name ) {
        // Append `[]` to the name to get multiple values
        // Use in_array() to check whether the current option should be checked
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '[]" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $value, '"', in_array( $value, $meta ) ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' /> ', $name, '<br/>';
    }
    break;

// In save():
// Line 358: replace it by:
$old = get_post_meta($post_id, $name, 'multicheck' != $field['type'] /* If multicheck this can be multiple values */);
// Lines 409-413: Wrap them in an else-clause, and prepend them by:
if ( 'multicheck' == $field['type'] ) {
    // Do the saving in two steps: first get everything we don't have yet
    // Then get everything we should not have anymore
    if ( empty( $new ) ) {
        $new = array();
    }
    $aNewToAdd = array_diff( $new, $old );
    $aOldToDelete = array_diff( $old, $new );
    foreach ( $aNewToAdd as $newToAdd ) {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $name, $newToAdd, false );
    }
    foreach ( $aOldToDelete as $oldToDelete ) {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $name, $oldToDelete );
    }
} else {
    // The original lines 409-413
}
```

Two extra changes to prevent PHP warnings when `WP_DEBUG` is enabled:

```
// Line 337:
if ( ! isset( $_POST['wp_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
// Line 359:
$new = isset( $_POST[$field['id']] ) ? $_POST[$field['id']] : null;
```

With these changes, you can use a "multicheck" by defining it like this:

```
array(
    'name' => 'Multicheck',
    'id' => $prefix . 'multicheck',
    'type' => 'multicheck',
    'options' => array(
        'a' => 'Apple',
        'b' => 'Banana',
        'c' => 'Cherry',
    ),
)
```

Comment: @Jan: Thank you very much for this answer, it's a big work. One question: As I said above I'm test this function with list of categories. I'm try assign several categories to page and nothing happens, even one category doesn't accept. 
In my template I'm use 

$catid = get_post_meta($post->ID,'mtb_category',true); query_posts('cat='.$catid);

Maybe you see whats wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @Denis: The comments are not the best way to do this, maybe you can ask an additional question? Make sure to include all your code, and output of `var_dump()` along they way, so we know what is going on.

Comment: @Jan: I check my database and see that my multicheck is saved separate.
Looks now:
http://imgur.com/dX76l.png
Must be:
http://imgur.com/m2KiI.png

I think problem with metaboxes, not with templates.

Comment: @Denis: That was intentional, that's why I meant with "distinct entries vs. one serialized entry". Your code should be `$catids = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mtb_category', false); query_posts( array( 'cat' => $catids ) );`. And maybe [replace query_posts() with get_posts()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: @Denis: I'm sorry, you should not use `cat` if you pass an array to `query_posts()`, but `category__in`. `cat` only accepts a comma-separated list of array ID's, but `category__in` accepts an array of category ID's, like we use here.

Comment: @Jan: You are SUPER MEGA MASTER. Thank you very much, this resolve my problem. I hope that many people find this post useful.

Comment: @ jan - Brilliant ! Someone just asked a question about this answer - how to save serialized data. you can find it here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36621/multiplile-values-checkbox-or-select-in-custom-meta-box/. I have answered - but I believe But all credits must go to you.