# Meta Box multi checkbox in template

Tags: metabox

I've used [this check meta box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6513/multicheck-box-for-post-metabox) in my functions.php but I don't understand how I can get the meta data. I'm trying to output if a product is still available or not.

Metabox setup:

```
/* Array of the meta box options. */
$meta_boxes = array(
    'affiliate-url' => array( 'name' => 'Affiliate_url', 'title' => __('Affiliate URL (generated)', 'hybrid'), 'type' => 'text' ),  
    'original-url' => array( 'name' => 'Original_url', 'title' => __('Original URL', 'hybrid'), 'type' => 'text' ),         
    'product-id' => array( 'name' => 'Product_ID', 'title' => __('Product ID', 'hybrid'), 'type' => 'text' ),           
    'normal-price' => array( 'name' => 'Normal_price', 'title' => __('Normal Price', 'hybrid'), 'type' => 'text' ),     
    'discount-price' => array( 'name' => 'Discount_price', 'title' => __('Discount Price', 'hybrid'), 'type' => 'text' ),
    'sizes-available' => array(
        'name' => 'Sizes_available',
        'title' => __('Currently available:', 'hybrid'),
        'type' => 'check',
        'options' => array(
            'XS' => 'Extra Small',
            'S' => 'Small',
            'M' => 'Medium',
            'L' => 'Large',
            'XL' => 'Extra Large',
            'XXL' => 'Extra Extra Large',                                               
),
```

Template setup:

```
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 product-info">
                                <h5>AVAILABLE IN</h5>
                                <ul>
                                        <li>Small</li>
                                        <li><strike>Medium</strike> <small>(sold out)</small></li>
                                        <li>Large</li>
                                        <li>Xtra Large</li>
                                        <li>Xtra Xtra large</li>    
                                </ul>                                                                                                                   
                            </div>
```

I need to output the list and place `<strike>$size</strike> <small> (sold out)</small>`.

Normaly I use `<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Sizes_available', true) ) : ?>` to check if something is filled in the meta box but this doesn't apply for a 'checked' output.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be made in the side of the template. First get all the sizes into an array:

```
$allSizes = array(

    'XS' => 'Extra Small',
    'S' => 'Small',
    'M' => 'Medium',
    'L' => 'Large',
    'XL' => 'Extra Large',
    'XXL' => 'Extra Extra Large',

);

echo '<ul>';
$outStock = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Sizes_available', true);
```

Then let's compare if one of the sizes is out of stock and output accordingly:

```
foreach($allSizes as $key => $size){
    if(in_array($key, $outStock)){
        echo "<li><strike>$size</strike> <small>(sold out)</small></li>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li>$size</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Hi Macro, 

This gives me the array but won't strike if something is sold out yet..

Comment: Yes, complete list without a strike. In WP I've checked 'medium' and saved the post.

Comment: Array ( [0] => M [1] => L ) . (and thank you for helping me out!)

Comment: I have edited the code to add the $key, maybe that fixes the problem. It should.