# Multiplile values checkbox or select in custom meta box

Tags: custom-field, metabox, customization

I have followed the great answer by [Jan Fabry](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8/jan-fabry) in this question .

[How to make multicheck for post/page meta box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/how-to-make-multicheck-for-post-page-meta-box)

this works great. My question though would be , what if someone WANTS a serialized value (array  e.g. :"banana,apple,grapes" in ONE field ? ) and not separate values ?

It is strange how in all the tutorials, example, and classes, everyone ignores multiple selection (also in select list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In his answer ,  Jan Fabry made a brilliant solution, but it saves the values one by one (for each his own field )

for your question, we need to "reverse" that , but it is actually easy .

BEFORE lines 409-413 , Jan Fabry made an if-else clause to seperate values into fields and save / update. we do not need it .

Instead , we take the already constructed array and save it as a whole.
so you just need to add this instead of the whole bigger clause (and do not forget to drop the ELSE:

```
  if ( 'multicheck' == $field['type'] ) {
        // If it is a multicheck , implode the array and get a string...
    $new =implode(",", $new);
    }
```

That´s all . 
and do not foget to thatnk JAN Fabry for it - not me :-)